# write to file from callback

Tags: matlab, file-io, serial-port

I have a device on my serial port which spits out several lines of text after receiving the character `h`. I want to put these lines of text into a file using Matlab.

This is my callback `fromBox.m`:

```
function fromBox = intcon1(val1, obj, eventStruct, val2)              
s = evalin('base','s');
textFromBox = evalin('base','textFromBox');                           

thisLine = char(fgets(s));                                            

fprintf(textFromBox,thisLine);                                        
disp(thisLine);
```

This is the script:

```
path = '/dev/tty.usb*';

% log file
system('touch test.csv');
textFromBox = fopen('test.csv');

s = serial(strcat(ls(path)));
fopen(s);

% Serial port settings:
s.BytesAvailableFcnMode = 'terminator';
s.BytesAvailableFcn = @fromBox;

helpCmd = char('h');

% print the string to the serial port
fprintf(s,helpCmd);
```

I can see from `disp` that I'm reading in the lines, but the file remains empty. How do I get the callback function to write to the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not close your file. You need to call

```
fclose( textFromBox  );
```

somewhere at the end of your code (when you are done writing). Otherwise the new content is not available for other applications.

Now you seem to want to write lines in the file every time you receive characters on your serial port. You could place your `fclose` instruction at the end of your main code, but there is a chance that you will be closing the file before having received the reply from the serial port, so your callback will not be able to write anyway.

The best way to handle it, is to let the callback take care of all the file management.
For example:

In your main code, just declare:

```
logFileName = 'test.csv' ;
%// ... some code ...
s.BytesAvailableFcn = { @fromBox , logFileName } ;
```

Then in your callback:

```
function fromBox( obj , eventStruct, logFile)              

thisLine = char( fgets(obj) );

fid = fopen( logFile , 'at' ) ;
fprintf( fid , '%s\n' , thisLine ) ;
fclose( fid ) ;

disp(thisLine);
```

Note that I corrected the way `fromBox.m` was declared. This way the first argument inside is the calling object, so you already have a reference to your serial port object (no need to call `evalin`, avoid if you can).

In the definition of the callback function `s.BytesAvailableFcn = { @fromBox , logFileName } ;`, we also send an additional parameter (the log file name), note the syntax: cell array containing the function handle then all the parameters. This also get rid of the last call to `evalin`.

The callback takes care of all the file management every time it receives a string it open/write/close the logfile.